# SharePoint 2007 List Multi Line field does not "unescape" HTML automatically?

Tags: 2007, textarea

I create a custom aspx file with a textarea field. I used Javascript to collect the data in this field and perform a `escape` on it so that when the user want to see this data again in the custom aspx file, I just need to `unescape` it.

Unfortunately, it seems that SharePoint 2007 will just insert the field as

```
First%0A%20%20%20%201.%20English%0A%20%20%20%202.%20English%0A%0A%uF046%uF069%uF072%uF073%uF074%0A1.%09%uF045%uF06E%uF067%uF06C%uF069%uF073%uF068%0A2.%09%uF045%uF06E%uF067%uF06C%uF069%uF073%uF068%0A
```

The original text that the user type is

```
First
    1. English
    2. English
```

What should I do in order to make everything (textarea and SharePoint 2007 text field) to give me the same original text rather than some special encoding?

Appreciate any insight & help offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what field you are using, but you can set a multiline text field to be RichText and it will save the HTML formatting and display it as it was inserted.